# Send ModelError to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have `Index.cshtml` View. And I have a method in controller, that can return a ModelError:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(string folderName)
    {
        try
        {
            //some stuff
        }
        catch //if folder with same name already exist
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Forlder with name " + folderName + "already exist");
            return Redirect(HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);
        }
        return Redirect(HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);
    }
```

The problem is, that when page reloads there is nothing in `@Html.ValidationSummary()`

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  //some stuff
  return View();
}
```

Comment: `AddModelError` is for adding an error to the existing view - it will be displayed if you use `return View(...)` (it does not apply if you redirect)

Comment: @StephenMuecke oh, I see. Is there an another way?

Comment: Send it in the request as a query string or route value, or add it to `TempData` and retrieve it in the GET method, or just use `return View()`

Comment: If the you want to display error in the same page from where it is posted then why don't you return the view itself with proper model with it?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I can be on `/Home/Index` or `/Home/Index/?path=something`, or in` /Home/Index/?path=something%path=something2 `and I need to return current page with error. Error should be executed from `Create` method.

Answer (score 0):

ModelState would not work in your case. 
You can use TempData.
`ModelState.AddModelError()` use `TempData["YourKey"].Add(Forlder with name " + folderName + "already exist")`
Then in _Layout.cshtml use:

```
@{ string notification = (string)TempData["YourKey"];}
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(notification ){
     @notification 
}
```